# Count unique dates from log list if matches cell

Tags: excel

I have a list of logged working hours by company employees. I'm looking for a function that can count the number of unique dates each employee has logged, as showed in the image below.

```
Emplyee     Date            Employee    Unique logged dates
John        2016-08-20      John        3
John        2016-08-21      Fredrik     5
John        2016-08-22      Josefine    2
Fredrik     2016-08-20          
Fredrik     2016-08-21          
Fredrik     2016-08-22          
Fredrik     2016-08-23          
Fredrik     2016-08-24          
Josefine    2016-08-20          
Josefine    2016-08-21
```

[Here's an example of the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76DPy.png)

With this function I can count the number of unique dates but not in regards to the list of employees. So a function to come up with the "Unique logged dates"

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B11<>"")/COUNTIF(B2:B11,B2:B11))
```

Comment: Can you post that table as text too? (Into your original post, and use `{}` formatting)

Comment: Are the dates always unique (per name section), as in your example? If so, you could just do a COUNTIF formula and go off the names in column A instead of the dates.

Comment: @BruceWayne, now you have the table. Your function almost works but it doesn't show the exact right number when I scale it up. Looses a few dates. Would really appreciate another try though. Thx

Comment: @tigeravatar, there can be multiple dates. So one person can have many logs with the same date (there are also hours to the list which were not important here).

Answer (score 0):

You're close, I think this should work for you (I assume your column A has the names, B has the date, and `D2` is a name):

`=RoundUp(SumProduct((($A$2:$A$11=D2))/Countif($B$2:$B$11,$B$2:$B$11)),0)`

and enter as an array (with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

Comment: As I wrote earlier your functions is almost there but when scaled up the result turns out to be lower than the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided example, in cell E2 and copied down is this ***array*** formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$100=D2,IF($B$2:$B$100<>"",MATCH($B$2:$B$100,$B$2:$B$100,0))),ROW($A$2:$A$100)-ROW($A$2)+1),1))
```

Note that array formulas must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and not just <kbd>Enter</kbd>